# Problems installing Laravel 4.2.0 using composer clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am trying to install Laravel using Composer but I keep getting the following error:

> Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /homepages/45/d487622789/htdocs/laravel/artisan on line 46
>
> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /homepages/45/d487622789/htdocs/laravel/artisan on line 46
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

I've had a look online but I can't seem to find anyone with the same problem.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check you php version: `php -v` because [Laravel require](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#server-requirements) php>=5.4. You need probably to update your version

Explanation: [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) were introduced in PHP 5.3, and you're running an older PHP version. That's why you got this error ( PHP parser didn't expect a `\` )